# <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" /> using IIS Express -> HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, iis-express

I'm trying to test client certificate authentication with `IIS Express`. Is it possible or do I need to use `IIS`?

I have modified my web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="SslRequireCert" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Guide that I use:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/01/11/using-client-certificates-in-net-part-1-introduction/

`.vs\config\applicationhost.config` looks like this, no deny or allowOverride set to false.:

```
<security>
    <access sslFlags="None" />
    ...
</security>
```

Error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.
>
> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `.vs\config\applicationhost.config` I found these lines:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="security">
                <section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Changed it to this and now it works.

```
<section name="access" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Comment: Neither IIS nor IIS Express recommends you configure that in web.config. You should use a location tag to configure it in applicationHost.config, and use tools such as Jexus Manager would make it easy to achieve.

Comment: @LexLi Since it is IIS Express and I only use it for development I think this is OK. Production is different but not the case here.

Comment: The changes you made in web.config should trigger the exact 500.19 error once putting into production environment with full IIS default configuration. That's why I wrote the comments so future readers are warned.

Comment: @LexLi That's fair but since I edited `applicationhost.config` I saw it as implicit. I don't think it deserves to be voted down because it fixed the error.

Comment: **It only hides the error on your machine.** However, it opens up a security hole on others' machine if they blindly follow your words. Why cannot I down vote it then?

Comment: @LexLi Standard is `None` and `sslFlags` is the only attribute so I don't see the hole. IIS Express is not intended for public use either. It is your vote so you can do what you wan't. :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access

Comment: I hope that you can understand the security hole is opened when you modify overrideModeDefault. Once changed anyone can override this in their web.config and turn off HTTPS.

Comment: @LexLi Yes, but if you look at the code default is `None`. What value could they change to so it would be a security hole? Enable overriding is not a security hole in itself, it depends on what the attacker can do.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this entirely in IIS Express, using applicationhost.config.
This great article helped me: https://improveandrepeat.com/2017/07/how-to-configure-iis-express-to-accept-ssl-client-certificates/

It's making these two changes to the applicationhost.config to accept client certificates and to ask for them

```
<access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert" />
```

and

```
<iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true">
            </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>
```

Comment: For testing, you can also set these options in IIS Express, in the local applicationhost.Config file, located in "Documents\IISExpress\config".
src https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api